# "Choice Column" SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, custom-list

I had created a choice column in SharePoint with "or specify value" and then I edited this list in Info-path. I deleted this "Drop-down menu" and added one from Info-path. But now I do not get "Specify value in a text box" option when I publish it. Before editing it in Info-path I had it so that there was a drop-down menu to choose from and if the value did not exist in the drop down then the user would specify it in a drop-box. The only downfall with this was that the drop-down did not update the information once the user enters a specific value. So I thought of using Info-path to provide me a workaround. However, now I do not have the previous functionality at all. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, drop down controls cannot do that OOB. But combo or Multiple Selection List boxes can, if you can use one of those instead.